# Programatically created UIDatepicke done and cancle button is not working

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

This is my UIDatePicker code but in that picker, done and cancle button is not working ...please help me.... i also add here my done and cancle button methods here..Please give me a proper suggessions for how it works properly.

```
if (textField.tag==Jobdatetxt.tag)
        {
            [Jobdatetxt resignFirstResponder];
            [data.toolbar removeFromSuperview];

            UITextField *lagFreeField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
            [self.view.window addSubview:lagFreeField];
            [lagFreeField becomeFirstResponder];
            [lagFreeField resignFirstResponder];
            [lagFreeField removeFromSuperview];
            //////////////////////////////////////////////// DATE OF JOB////////////////////////////////////////////////

            pickerDate   = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,result.height - 216, result.width, 216)];
            [pickerDate setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
            pickerDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            [self.view.window addSubview:pickerDate];

            toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
            toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

            toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0,result.height - 266,result.width,50);

            cancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [cancel setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cancel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [cancel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
            cancel.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(CancelClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            cancel.tag = textField.tag;
            cancel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 30);

            [toolbar addSubview:cancel];

            doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            doneButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
            doneButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(DoneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            doneButton.tag = textField.tag;
            doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(result.width - 80, 10, 70, 30);

            [toolbar addSubview:doneButton];

            [self.view.window addSubview:toolbar];
        }
```

// Done Button method

```
-(IBAction)DoneClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
[pickerDate removeFromSuperview];
    [toolbar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

//Cancle Button Method

```
-(IBAction)CancelClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [pickerDate removeFromSuperview];
    [toolbar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: You add your pickerDate and toolbar to the window. but want to remove from the superview. Only add them to a view: [self.view addSubview:pickerDate]; [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

Comment: thanks dude..done button issue is resolve but selected value is not getting in textfeild